# Two Scroll Rects overlapping in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scroll rects overlapping in unity I have done this so I can have image and text next to each other that change sides for every time they are made, is there a way I can have them both scroll at the same time and point as currently they only scroll individually

I used two overlapping scroll rects and expected them to both work at the same time

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe that's a valid use case for the built-in ScrollView.  You'll need to write your own implementation instead that can handle your use case.